# Find all files in a shared special folder (Virtual Folders)

Tags: c#, windows, file, special-folders

Im looking for a way to find all files in an shared special folder (Virtual Folder).
The `Desktop` for example is an shared folder, there is a public `Desktop` for all users and a private `Desktop`. By navigating with the file explorer to `Desktop` you will see the contents of both desktops merged together.

---

Example:

Shared folder for all:

```
dir C:\Users\Public\Desktop
Testfile1
Testfile2
```

Folder for the current user:

```
dir C:\Users\usera\Desktop
Testfile3
Testfile4
```

Now I want to get all files from `Testfile1` till `Testfile4` by looping trough `C:\Users\usera\Desktop`

Someone has a clue howto get a list of the files of both directories merged together?
Also not only for Desktop, there are other folders that behave the same way.

---

Pseudocode:

```
arrayDesktop = FunctionThatGetsAllFilesFrom(@"C:\Usera\Desktop");
foreach (var file in arrayDesktop)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

this should now print out

```
Testfile1
Testfile2
Testfile3
Testfile4
```

Comment: For reference, the official name of these types of folders is [Virtual Folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder#Virtual_folders). Not to be confused with the (identically named!) [Virtual Folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_folder#Windows)

Answer (score 0):

They are separate folders on the file system.  Windows just combines them both to display on the desktop.  You are going to have to get all the files from both folders and combine them into a single list.

You can get the list of files in a given folder with [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Once you have the files from both folders, you can combine them with the Linq [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method.

Comment: I know that these are two seperate folders, the thing is that there is not only Desktop shared, also other folders. And I don't want to check them all. I wanted to know if there is a method that does the "merging" for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` and `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory)` to get the files on your Desktop and the Public one respectively.

For other Virtual Folders you can look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). But you still have to merge all the files yourself.

Comment: as I said before, I dont want only the Desktop, I want also the other `VirtualFolders`

Comment: You can find other Virtual Folder in the documentation. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested code so forgive any errors, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\Users"))
{
    string fullDir = Path.Combine(dir, "Desktop");

    if (Directory.Exists(fullDir))
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(fullDir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you're running this as an administrator though, you're likely to run into security issues i.e. unable to read the directory.  In this instance, you're going to need the `System.Net.NetworkCredential` object and store the admin account in local cache - something like this.

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\computer-uri"), "Basic", credential);
```

Comment: That does not match the question. Your code works only for Desktop.

Comment: @Eun it seems others have made the same "mistake", your question is confusing. Perhaps if you provided some pseudo-code of some kind to show us what you're looking for?